# How would I completely restart a for loop or an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I am looking for an answer to EITHER of these two questions because either one will work for my code.  Is there a function or something that will completely restart a `for` loop or rerun an `if` statement?  For the `for` loop, let's say it is

```
for(int i = 0; i<=30; i++){
   //code here
}
```

and by this point it had gotten to `i = 5`, how would I tell it to go back to `i = 0`?

For the `if` statement, let's say the `if` statement was:

```
if(i == 1 && j == 2){
  //more code here
}
```

How would I tell it, at the end of the `if` statement, if the `if` statement is `true`, to completely rerun the `if` statement?

Comment: @Ed is right, use recursion!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR** It sounds like you want a `while` loop or possibly a recursive function.

## The `for` Loop Version

You can't restart an `if` statement, but you can modify your loop control variable in the `for` loop. Just do `i = 0;` and watch out for infinite loops, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    // do stuff
    if(someCondition) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

This isn't very good style, though, and can lead to some devilish bugs that are hard to find. People aren't used to looking for modifications to the loop control variable inside the `for` loop because it's one of those things that You. Just. Don't. Do.

## The `while` Loop Version

So, instead of a `for` loop, you should use a `while` loop if you plan to modify `i` inside the loop.

Example:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 30) {
    // do stuff
    if(someCondition) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

## The Recursive Function Version

Depending on what you really want to do, you might also consider creating a function and calling it recursively:

```
function myFunction() {
    // do stuff
    if(someCondition) {
        myFunction(); // this is the recursion
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    myFunction();
}
```

With all of these approaches, watch out for infinite loops! They are easy to create if you aren't careful.

Comment: Just for reminder, If you are using Recursive Function, remember that there is a nested depth in Java.It would throw stackOverflowException in some case.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful doing this. You can get stuck in a loop you can't get out of.

```
for(int i = 0; i<=30; i++){
   //code here
    if (some condition) {i=0;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you can use `continue` and `break` statements for your problem, but they won't initialize back to `i = 0`.

However, for your problem the following is suitable:

```
for(i=0; i<30; i++){
    if(condition check) {i=0;}
    // other code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By setting i to -1 you can restart the for loop but be careful do not enter an endless loop by the way you set i to -1.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: by setting i to -1 when it goes to “for” statement ,i++ increment i from -1 to 0 , then condition is checked after that it enters the for block while i=0. therefore it acts as if for loop restarted

Answer (score -2):

All the other answers are incorrect, because on the first iteration `i=0;` sets `i` to `0` and then `i++` in the for loop increases it to `1`, so basically you never start from `i=0` again, which will result in always skipping the first array element if you want to check an Array `a[i]`.